# Get realtime data using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hello guys i am trying to show real time loop data. using AJAX i want when AJAX run its get real time number update from action page loop.

```
$.ajax({
            url: "number.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                name: name
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
            /// some code to get result
           }
```

and loop page 
number.php

```
<?php
$id =$_POST['id'];
 while(true) // no matter
    { 
echo '<script>
        int i = 0;
        int ii += i;
        print(i); // i want to shoe this value 
        i++;
      </script>'
 }
```

Comment: A newer approach to this is to use sockets, see https://socket.io/

Comment: You probably want to try [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) instead. AJAX is not designed for the kind of the data exchange you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You're posting `name` and retrieving `$_POST['id']`? The question very unclear about what it is you're trying to do. I don't see why you would need to involve PHP at all, when looking at your examples.

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do can be achieved by using **web-sockets** or **http-long-polling**

I would suggest that you use websockets, using **[Ratchet](http://socketo.me/)**,
Ratchet is a loosely coupled PHP library providing developers with tools to create real time, bi-directional applications between clients and servers over Web-sockets.

Using ajax is kinda not a good idea, because you have to send request to the server after every X seconds, to fetch data even if there are no changes in the server. doing this is more like you are DDos attacking your own server without knowing that.

> But if you insist on ajax you would run a function that will send a
>   request to the php script every x seconds, here's how you would do
>   that with Ajax.

```
$('document').ready(function () {
 setInterval(function () {getRealData()}, 1000);//request every x seconds

 }); 

function getRealData() {
$.ajax({
         url: "number.php",
         type: "POST",
         data: {
             name: name
         },
         cache: false,
         success: function () {
             /// some code to get result
         }
     }
 }
```

NB: AS I have said above better have a look into websockets.

Comment: I might suggest that instead of using setInterval, use setTimeout in the previous call's "complete" function to line up the next call. Otherwise connection problems or latency might result in AJAX calls getting backed up.